# MySQL: Suggesting objects (optimizing a multi-join query)

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, optimization

**Goal:** Suggest objects based on user's choices

**Data:** Table containing info on how users would order a subset of objects from the worst to the best; Example:

```
          1 2 3 4 5 6
    John: A B G J S O
    Mary: A C G L
    Joan: B C L J K
    Stan: G J C L
```

There's about 20 times as many users as objects, every user's lineup contains 50-200 objects.

**The table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pref` (
  `usr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `obj` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ord` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `u_o` (`usr`,`obj`),
  KEY `u` (`usr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Basic idea:** Iterate within user's objects starting from the second worst, building pairs (A > B); look for them in other users' lineups and list items better than A according to those users.

**Query:**

```
SELECT e.obj, COUNT(e.obj) AS rate
FROM pref a, pref b, pref c, pref d, pref e

WHERE a.usr = '222' # step 1: select a pair of objects A, B, where A is better than B according to user X
AND a.obj = '111'
AND b.usr = a.usr
AND b.ord < a.ord

AND c.obj = a.obj # step 2: find users thinking that object A is better than B
AND d.obj = b.obj
AND d.ord < c.ord
AND d.usr = c.usr 

AND e.ord > c.ord # step 3: find objects better than A according to these users
AND e.usr = c.usr

GROUP BY e.obj
ORDER BY rate DESC;
```

Aliases:
`a` object A ('111'), current user ('222')
`b` object B, worse than A according to current user (has lower value of 'ord' than A)
`c` object A in other user's lineup
`d` object B in other user's lineup
`e` object better than A in other user's lineup

The execution plan (ouo and uo being the indexes as suggested by **Quassnoi**):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | ouo,uo        | ouo  | 8       | const,const         |    1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | ouo,uo        | uo   | 4       | const               |   86 | Using where                                  | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ref  | ouo,uo        | ouo  | 4       | db.b.obj            |  587 | Using index                                  | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | ouo,uo        | ouo  | 8       | const,db.d.usr      |    1 | Using where; Using index                     | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref  | uo            | uo   | 4       | db.d.usr            |   80 | Using where                                  | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The query seems to work fine as long as the dataset is not too big; any ideas on how to streamline it to support larger datasets?

Comment: How many objects per user will be there in average?

Comment: Around 50-200 objects per user.

Comment: Do you really need this ranking exactly the way it is now? The query could be easily improved if not for that ranking. Also, could you please post the execution plan for the query?

Comment: Do you mean the ranking contained in the output of the query (COUNT(e.obj) AS rate)?

Basically I need to be able to predict which objects are more probable to be rated high by the user according to the order of previous objects he lined up. If I can achieve that somehow else, great; I couldn't think of anything less demanding though.

Comment: I added the plan to the post.

Comment: I tried to create a more simple rating system which should be faster. Could you please check it?

Comment: Looks promising! :)
I'll give it a go. Might be just the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is fine, just create the following indexes:

```
pref (obj, usr, ord)
pref (usr, ord)
```

**Update:**

Try this syntax.

The rating system is simpler but quite similar: it gives almost same rating on the test random results I created.

```
SELECT  oa.obj, SUM(weight) AS rate
FROM    (
        SELECT  usr, ord,
                (
                SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    pref a
                JOIN    pref ob
                ON      ob.obj = a.obj
                WHERE   ob.usr = o.usr
                        AND a.usr = 50
                        AND a.ord <
                        (
                        SELECT  ord
                        FROM    pref ai
                        WHERE   ai.usr = 50
                                AND ai.obj = 75
                        )
                        AND ob.ord < o.ord
                ) AS weight
        FROM    pref o
        WHERE   o.obj = 75
        HAVING  weight >= 0
        ) ow
JOIN    pref oa
ON      oa.usr = ow.usr
        AND oa.ord > ow.ord
GROUP BY
        oa.obj
ORDER BY
        rate DESC
```

This query gives the weight to each item rated higher than `A` by all users who rated `A`.

The weight is equal to the number of items rated below `A` by both users.

Comment: Thanks! It's too bad though. For a user with 150 objects in a table with 250k rows it takes around 8-9 seconds (returning 376 rows). :/

I tried changing the table type from MyISAM to MEMORY, but for some reason it doesn't want to use multi-column indexes then. Weird.